# Check_box_tag - pre-checked conditional on values in @array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller

How do I implement a check_box_tag with pre-checked boxes which match the values contained in an instance variable `@array`:

```
= form_tag xxx_path, :method => :get do 
  - @all_names.each do |name|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "names[#{name}]", CHECKED IF name in @array
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

Edit - Controller first:

```
  def index
    if params[:ratings]
      @filtered_ratings = params[:ratings]
      @movies = Movie.find(:all, :conditions => ["rating IN (?)", @filtered_ratings], :order => params[:sort])
    else
      @movies = Movie.find(:all, :order => params[:sort])   
    end
  end
```

Now view:

```
= form_tag movies_path, :method => :get do
  Include: 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, @filtered_ratings.include?(rating) ? true : false
= submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
= form_tag xxx_path, :method => :get do 
  - @all_ratings.each do |rating|
    = rating
    = check_box_tag "ratings[#{rating}]", 1, @filtered_ratings.include?(rating) ? true : false
  = submit_tag 'Refresh'
```

In the controller:

```
def index
  @filtered_ratings = params[:ratings] || [] # if no params[:ratings] then assign empty array
  @movies = Movie.order(params[:sort])
  @movies = @movies.where(rating: params[:ratings]) if params[:ratings].present?
end
```

Comment: Thanks this looks like it could work - how do I catch the `nil` object error (I guess for boxes that don't show up in the `@array`)?

Comment: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?

Comment: There could be cases where none of the boxes is pre-checked.

Comment: @filtered_ratings - and `names` is actually `ratings`

Comment: Can you post your controller's action OR post the section of code where you set your two arrays? (`@all_names` and the other array you want to compare)

Comment: See new update also, I refactored your controller's action. Tell me if it does not work (but it should) and if you don't understand everything @StefanJansen

Comment: Thanks a lot again @MrYoshiji. Looks much cleaner. But without pre-selected ratings I still seem to be getting the nil object error when trying to pre-check boxes. Plus I'm not getting any movies in my views if there are no ratings as selection criteria.

Comment: what is the output of `params[:ratings]` ?

Comment: it's empty unless a rating has been selected.

Comment: So what is the output of it when a rating has been selected??!! I obviously asked that!! I know its empty if we dont select one!! Just tell me what is the EXACT output of params[:ratings] when you select a random rating. you can see it in your console, or eventually call `- raiser params[:ratings] if params[:ratings].present?` in your view to see what it contains

Comment: Sorry, should have realized that. Got it to work in the meantime, ratings showed up as keys in the array, not as values. Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!